# URLhashListener pegando o item errado (Owl Carousel)

Tags: jquery, css, plugin, owl-carousel, carousel

Estou usando Owl Carousel numa landing page. adicionei algumas miniaturas, e usei o URLhashListener para associar as miniaturas á respectiva imagem, mas o link tá abrindo a imagem errada. Parece que o script está calculando o valor errado, as imagens ficam 2 atrasadas.

está em homologação aqui: http://aresdapraca.itlean.com.br/

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você testou tirar o Loop ?

Comment: funcionou sem loop!
Será que só tem esse jeito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Descobri o problema. É um bug do próprio Owl Carousel.

Pode voltar o loop.

`loop: true`.

Pode tirar aquelas outras opções:

```
URLhashListener:true,
startPosition: 'URLHash'
```

Esses dois de cima é só para alterar a URL, o Hash:

`#one` `#two`.

Agora o que você tem que fazer é importar esse arquivo de script abaixo no seu código, abaixo do `owl.carousel.min.js` ou `owl.carousel.js`.

https://rawgit.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel2/develop/src/js/owl.hash.js

Aí está o LINK, mas você pode salvar a página como arquivo JS pra você ter o arquivo, porquê se o LINK quebrar você fica sem.